# Correct ELK multiline regular expression?

Tags: regex, logstash, multiline, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am newbie to ELK and i'm writing a config file which uses multiline and we need to write a pattern for input data

```
110000|read|<soapenv:Envelope>
<head>hello<head>
<body></body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope>
<body></body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
210000|read|<soapenv:Envelope>
<head>hello<head>
<body></body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope>
<body></body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
370000|read|<soapenv:Envelope>
<head>hello<head>
<body></body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope>
<body></body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and config file used is :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/opt/test5/practice_new/xml_input.dat"
     start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline
  {
   pattern => "^%{INT}\|%{WORD}\|<soapenv:Envelope*>\|<soapenv"
   negate => true
   what => "previous"
  }
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{DATA:method_id}\|%{WORD:method_type}\|%{GREEDYDATA:request}\|%{GREEDYDATA:response}" ]
  }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "xml"
  }
stdout {}
}
```

But the pattern used in it does not match for my requirement.

please suggest me the correct pattern.

Expected output :

For 1st log

```
method_id- 110000

method type-

request-

response-
```

For 2nd log

```
 method id- 210000

    method type-

    request-

    response-
```

similarly for the rest.

Comment: Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/lP5xef/1) (copy the regex from the regular expression field to try).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew can u help me with the regular expression for the following log

Comment: If the answer below does not work with my regex, you should not accept it.

Comment: use the link https://regex101.com/r/lP5xef/2

Comment: these are new set of logs on which i needed your help with the regular expression. please see the link

Comment: If it is a new question, post it, and provide 1) the new string format, 2) what you have, 3) what you tried, 4) what does not work, 5) how you want it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you'll have to fix your multiline pattern:

```
codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{NUMBER:method_id}\|%{DATA:method_type}\|<soapenv:Envelope>"
            negate => true
            what => previous
        }
```

Afterwards you can use the pattern Wiktor suggests in the comments:

```
(?m)^(?<method_id>\d+)\|(?<method_type>\w+)\|(?<request><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)\|(?<response><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)
```

Following results for the three log lines in your post on http://grokconstructor.appspot.com:
[image: results]

---

Your whole config might look like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/opt/test5/practice_new/xml_input.dat"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{NUMBER:method_id}\|%{DATA:method_type}\|<soapenv:Envelope>"
            negate => true
            what => previous
        }
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "(?m)^(?<method_id>\d+)\|(?<method_type>\w+)\|(?<request><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)\|(?<response><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)" ]
  }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "xml"
  }
stdout {}
}
```

Comment: Where should i use the pattern suggested by Wiktor ,as i'm getting error while using this in Grok.                                                                                                             Or should i use it in multiline pattern.?

Comment: I'm getting error while using the pattern (given by wiktor) in grok. Where should i use the pattern..?

Comment: See my edit. I can't test it myself, as I don't have a setup here, so I got to rely on the results from grokconstructor...

Comment: @ Phonolog can you help me with the configuration file for this XML data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861957/correct-regular-expression-for-the-input-log