# Correct regular expression for the input log

Tags: regex, logstash, multiline, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Input log looks like this, which contains data which are "|" sperated. The data contains  id | type | request | response

```
110000|read|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Bod<web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
<getLookUpService>
<serviceRequester>iOBD</serviceRequester>
<lineOfBusiness>mobility</lineOfBusiness>
<lookupAttribute>
<searchAttrValue>911425152231426</searchAttrValue>
</lookupAttribute>
</getLookUpService>
</web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<getLookUpServiceReturn>
<errorInfo>
<ErrorCode/>
<ErrorMessage/>
</errorInfo>
<lookupResponseList>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>region</attributeName>
<attributeValue>["Micromax"]</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>msisdn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Maharashtra"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imei</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"917756870222"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imsi</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"911425152231426"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_vendor</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"404909092353805"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_type</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"E311"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"1"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>g3</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>mms</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>gprs</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>streaming</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>ota</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>wap</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>os</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Google"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"4.4.2"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>camera</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>apn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>""AIRTELGPRS.COM,AIRTELMMS.COM""</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
</lookupResponseList>
</getLookUpServiceReturn>
</ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
210000|read|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Bod<web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
<getLookUpService>
<serviceRequester>iOBD</serviceRequester>
<lineOfBusiness>mobility</lineOfBusiness>
<lookupAttribute>
<searchAttrValue>911425152231426</searchAttrValue>
</lookupAttribute>
</getLookUpService>
</web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<getLookUpServiceReturn>
<errorInfo>
<ErrorCode/>
<ErrorMessage/>
</errorInfo>
<lookupResponseList>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>region</attributeName>
<attributeValue>["Micromax"]</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>msisdn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Maharashtra"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imei</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"917756870222"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imsi</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"911425152231426"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_vendor</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"404909092353805"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_type</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"E311"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"1"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>g3</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>mms</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>gprs</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>streaming</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>ota</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>wap</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>os</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Google"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"4.4.2"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>camera</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>apn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>""AIRTELGPRS.COM,AIRTELMMS.COM""</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
</lookupResponseList>
</getLookUpServiceReturn>
</ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
340000|read|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Bod<web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
<getLookUpService>
<serviceRequester>iOBD</serviceRequester>
<lineOfBusiness>mobility</lineOfBusiness>
<lookupAttribute>
<searchAttrValue>911425152231426</searchAttrValue>
</lookupAttribute>
</getLookUpService>
</web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<getLookUpServiceReturn>
<errorInfo>
<ErrorCode/>
<ErrorMessage/>
</errorInfo>
<lookupResponseList>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>region</attributeName>
<attributeValue>["Micromax"]</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>msisdn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Maharashtra"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imei</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"917756870222"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imsi</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"911425152231426"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_vendor</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"404909092353805"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_type</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"E311"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"1"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>g3</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>mms</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>gprs</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>streaming</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>ota</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>wap</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>os</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Google"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"4.4.2"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>camera</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>apn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>""AIRTELGPRS.COM,AIRTELMMS.COM""</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
</lookupResponseList>
</getLookUpServiceReturn>
</ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
450000|read|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Bod<web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
<getLookUpService>
<serviceRequester>iOBD</serviceRequester>
<lineOfBusiness>mobility</lineOfBusiness>
<lookupAttribute>
<searchAttrValue>911425152231426</searchAttrValue>
</lookupAttribute>
</getLookUpService>
</web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<getLookUpServiceReturn>
<errorInfo>
<ErrorCode/>
<ErrorMessage/>
</errorInfo>
<lookupResponseList>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>region</attributeName>
<attributeValue>["Micromax"]</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>msisdn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Maharashtra"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imei</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"917756870222"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imsi</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"911425152231426"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_vendor</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"404909092353805"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_type</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"E311"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"1"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>g3</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>mms</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>gprs</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>streaming</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>ota</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>wap</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>os</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Google"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"4.4.2"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>camera</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>apn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>""AIRTELGPRS.COM,AIRTELMMS.COM""</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
</lookupResponseList>
</getLookUpServiceReturn>
</ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
590000|read|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Bod<web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
<getLookUpService>
<serviceRequester>iOBD</serviceRequester>
<lineOfBusiness>mobility</lineOfBusiness>
<lookupAttribute>
<searchAttrValue>911425152231426</searchAttrValue>
</lookupAttribute>
</getLookUpService>
</web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>|<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<getLookUpServiceReturn>
<errorInfo>
<ErrorCode/>
<ErrorMessage/>
</errorInfo>
<lookupResponseList>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>region</attributeName>
<attributeValue>["Micromax"]</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>msisdn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Maharashtra"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imei</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"917756870222"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imsi</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"911425152231426"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_vendor</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"404909092353805"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_type</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"E311"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"1"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>g3</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>mms</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>gprs</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>streaming</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>ota</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>wap</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>os</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Google"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"4.4.2"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>camera</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>apn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>""AIRTELGPRS.COM,AIRTELMMS.COM""</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
</lookupResponseList>
</getLookUpServiceReturn>
</ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

desired output:

1st log:

```
id- 110000

type-read

request-<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Bod<web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
<getLookUpService>
<serviceRequester>iOBD</serviceRequester>
<lineOfBusiness>mobility</lineOfBusiness>
<lookupAttribute>
<searchAttrValue>911425152231426</searchAttrValue>
</lookupAttribute>
</getLookUpService>
</web:getLookUpServiceDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

response-<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.lookup.sdp.bharti.ibm.com">
<getLookUpServiceReturn>
<errorInfo>
<ErrorCode/>
<ErrorMessage/>
</errorInfo>
<lookupResponseList>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>region</attributeName>
<attributeValue>["Micromax"]</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>msisdn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Maharashtra"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imei</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"917756870222"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>imsi</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"911425152231426"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_vendor</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"404909092353805"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_type</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"E311"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>device_version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"1"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>g3</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>mms</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>gprs</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>streaming</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>ota</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>wap</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>os</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Google"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>version</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"4.4.2"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>camera</attributeName>
<attributeValue>"Yes"</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
<mapEntry>
<attributeName>apn</attributeName>
<attributeValue>""AIRTELGPRS.COM,AIRTELMMS.COM""</attributeValue>
</mapEntry>
</lookupResponseList>
</getLookUpServiceReturn>
</ns:getLookUpServiceDetailsResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

for 2nd log :

```
id - 210000

type - read

request -

response -
```

Similarly for the "n" no. of logs

configuration file used:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/opt/test5/practice_new/final_xml.dat"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{NUMBER:method_id}\|%{DATA:method_type}\|<soapenv:Envelope>"
            negate => true
            what => previous
        }
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "(?m)^(?<method_id>\d+)\|(?<method_type>\w+)\|(?<request><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)\|(?<response><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)" ]
  }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "final"
  }
stdout {}
}
```

I tried using the regular expression in Grok but the current one is not working for the input logs.

please help me with the regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

The regex you currently are using is `(?m)^(?<method_id>\d+)\|(?<method_type>\w+)\|(?<request><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)\|(?<response><soapenv:Envelope>.*?</soapenv:Envelope>)`, and it can only parse out the 3rd and 4th columns if they start with `<soapenv:Envelope>` and end with `</soapenv:Envelope>` having `|` in between.

It seems you need a regex that will identify the 3rd column as a sequence of any chars other than `|` and the 4th column should gran any number of chars other than `|` up to the newline followed with 1 or more digits and then `|`.

Use

```
(?m)^(?<method_id>\d+)\|(?<method_type>\w+)\|(?<request>[^|]*)\|(?<response>[^|\n]*(?:\n(?!\d+\|)[^|\n]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PbGfA6/1).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - the Ruby modifier that makes `.` match line break chars
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?<method_id>\d+)` - Group "method": one or more digits
- `\|` - a pipe char
- `(?<method_type>\w+)` - Group "method_type": one or more letters, digits or `_`
- `\|` - a pipe
- `(?<request>[^|]*)` - Group "request": any 0+ chars other than `|`
- `\|` -  a pipe
- `(?<response>[^|\n]*(?:\n(?!\d+\|)[^|\n]*)*)` - Group "response":

  - `[^|\n]*` - any 0+ chars other than `|` and LF (newlines)
  - `(?:\n(?!\d+\|)[^|\n]*)*` - 0+ occurrences of:

    - `\n` - a newline
    - `(?!\d+\|)` - not followed with 1+ digits + `|`
    - `[^|\n]*` - any 0+ chars other than `|` and LF (newlines)

Comment: Thanks witkor for the reply

Comment: the above expression matches for the first log but fails to match the rest logs.

Comment: @Ritwik: Which logs? [It does match the previous ones (added at the bottom).](https://regex101.com/r/PbGfA6/2)

Comment: @witkor  yes, It does't match from 2nd log onwards.

Comment: @Ritwik: As you see in my regex demo, the bottom records are matched. Note you do not need the `(?m)` modifier, that seems redundant in this pattern. I also tested at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/, the regex is matching hte previous and the current log formats.

Comment: @Witkor when i'm trying to match the log with regular expression separately then it is matching for each logs. But when for all the with the regular expression then it only matches for 1st log

Comment: in grokdebug.herokuapp.com, i copied my all input log and used the expression to match but it only matches for the 1st log. I don't understand why it is not mapping for the rest of the logs

Comment: No idea, perhaps, your data is different from the one posted in the question. Check leading whitespace, maybe you need to add `\s*` after `^`.

Comment: @Witkor my data is same as mentioned above

Comment: There are total of 5 logs in the above question. And i'm parsing for all the 5 logs with your expression. But only the 1st log is being matched with the expression.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that on your side, you only get the results of the first *entry*? That means, the problem is with your configuration.

Comment: also when i'm trying to match my input with the expression in http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ ,it is also parsing for the 1st log

Comment: If you remember you have helped me with an similar XML data in past.Though the size of XML was small as compared to this one .But with the same configuration and with your regular expression all logs were been matched.In here i'm using the same configuration only the regular expression changes.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837326/correct-elk-multiline-regular-expression

Comment: At grokdebug.herokuapp.com, it only works for a single entry as far as I know. The regex works well. What I  suspect is that you need to configure the *multiline* part of your filter. Perhaps, all the named fields must be enumerated there. `pattern => "^%{NUMBER:method_id}\|%{DATA:method_type}\|%{DATA:request}\|%{DATA:response}"`. Or maybe even shorter - `pattern => "^%{NUMBER}\|%{DATA}\|%{DATA}\|%{DATA}"`

Comment: used your pattern, but still getting the same probelm.

Comment: Did you try to put *preivous* inside `"..."`? Like `what => "previous"`? Also, try adding `type => "raw-file"`. Or/and `pattern => "%{DATA}"`. See [this article](https://blog.lanyonm.org/articles/2015/12/29/log-aggregation-log4j-spring-logstash.html#raw-log4j-and-the-multiline-codec). Or `pattern => "^%{NUMBER}"`. I am out of ideas.